# get the result from column2 when column1 is selected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get the result from column2 when column1 is the case. I get the error '"%s: invalid identifier"' when I try the code below. This is a very simple example that I stripped from my code, but need it achieved this way.

```
CASE columnname

WHEN 'Column1' THEN 
 Column2

 END AS
 "MY RESULT"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
SELECT case WHEN columnname = 'Column1' 
THEN Column2
END as "MY RESULT"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I simplified the my code, but I forgot to mention there are multiple cases such as this: (I only want column1 to to take the column2's value)
CASE columnname
WHEN 'Column1' THEN 
 Column2
WHEN 'Column3' THEN 
 columnresult
 WHEN 'Column4' THEN 
 columnresult                                                     END AS
 "MY RESULT"

Comment: CASE
 WHEN Boolean_expression1 THEN expression1
 [[WHEN Boolean_expression2 THEN expression2] [...]]
 [ELSE expressionN]
 END

Comment: Yes this is what I have now, but it says Column2 is an invalid identifier (the column defiantly exists in the table)

Comment: Is "Column2" the name of the column ??

Comment: No, I just used it here to simplify, it is lastname, but in the actual query I substituted it: CASE WHEN columnname = 'firstname' THEN lastname. And it says lastname is invalid identifier, but the column exists (it is spelled correctly and there are no spaces or underscores or anything like that)

Comment: This what the result from sqlfiddle: Invalid column name 'columnname'.: SELECT CASE WHEN columnname= 'a' THEN b ELSE 'ERROR' END FROM x

Comment: "columnname" needs to be a real column name ...
SELECT 
CASE WHEN a = 'aa' THEN b 
ELSE 'ERROR' END 
FROM x

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33581/discussion-between-user2367789-and-bws)

Comment: but the case is based on the columnname not the value in the column
I have to the test the columnname not what the column's value is

Comment: BTW the columnname = 'a' syntax works in SQL Developer on ORACLE 11g